# How to bold searched content using only javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an auto suggest search using javascript. All things are working fine, now i wanted to make searched text bold in the list.

Is this possible when user search something then only search text become bold in the result list. For example if i search `one` then one will be bold in the list.

```js
var inputId  = 'filter-search';
var itemsData  = 'filter-value';
var displaySet = false;
var displayArr = [];

function getDisplayType(element) {
 var elementStyle = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
 return elementStyle.display;
}

document.getElementById(inputId).onkeyup = function() {
 var searchVal = this.value.toLowerCase();
 var filterItems = document.querySelectorAll('[' + itemsData + ']');
 for(var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
  if (!displaySet) {
   displayArr.push(getDisplayType(filterItems[i]));
  }
  filterItems[i].style.display = 'none';
  if(filterItems[i].getAttribute('filter-value').toUpperCase().indexOf(searchVal.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
   filterItems[i].style.display = displayArr[i];  
  }
 }
 displaySet = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter-search" />

<ul>
 <li filter-value="One Is">One Is (Uppercase)</li>
  <li filter-value="one is">one is (Lowercase)</li>
 <li filter-value="two">Two</li>
 <li filter-value="three">Three</li>
 <li filter-value="four">Four</li>
 <li filter-value="five" >Five</li>
 <li filter-value="six">Six</li>
 <li filter-value="seven">Seven</li>
 <li filter-value="eight">Eight</li>
 <li filter-value="nine">Nine</li>
 <li filter-value="ten" >Ten</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this via using below code

```
var textcontent = filterItems[i].textContent;
    var replacedval = "<strong>"+currval+"</strong>"
    var finalval = textcontent.replace(currval, replacedval);
   filterItems[i].innerHTML = finalval;
        filterItems[i].style.display = 'none';
```

Here is working JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ku5zv3dz/

Comment: Have defined var currval = this.value; in top.Please see jsfiddle for working solution

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the style of only a part of a text contained within an element.

To do what you ask, you have to create an additional element (say, a `<span>` element) which will contain only the text you want to make bold, and append it. Then, you have to remove the same text from the original element.

For example

```
<li filter-value="One Is">
  <span class="bold">One</span> Is (Uppercase)
</li>
```

Since you already know which part of the text has been searched, it should be trivial to do this using `String.replace()` and DOM manipulation methods like `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got. I'm a little confused with your toLowerCase and toUpperCase code, but for the most part this works. Type in 'o', or 'u', or any of the above to test. It'll bold just what you typed in (in lowercase, since that's what your code does..)

```
var inputId = 'filter-search';
var itemsData = 'filter-value';
var displaySet = false;
var displayArr = [];

function getDisplayType(element) {
  var elementStyle = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
  return elementStyle.display;
}

document.getElementById(inputId).onkeyup = function() {
  var searchVal = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var filterItems = document.querySelectorAll('[' + itemsData + ']');
  for (var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
    var elem = filterItems[i]; // assign it to a variable so that i don't have to constantly say filterItems[i]
    if (!displaySet) {
      displayArr.push(getDisplayType(elem));
    }
    elem.style.display = 'none';
    elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/<b>/g, '').replace(/<\/b>/g, ''); // strip away all previous bold
    if (elem.getAttribute('filter-value').toUpperCase().indexOf(searchVal.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
      elem.style.display = displayArr[i];
      if (searchVal.length > 0) {
        elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(searchVal, 'g'), '<b>' + searchVal + '</b>'); // replace search with bold
      }
    }
  }
  displaySet = true;
}
```

.

```
<input type="text" id="filter-search" />
<ul>
    <li filter-value="One Is">One Is (Uppercase)</li>
  <li filter-value="one is">one is (Lowercase)</li>
    <li filter-value="two">Two</li>
    <li filter-value="three">Three</li>
    <li filter-value="four">Four</li>
    <li filter-value="five" >Five</li>
    <li filter-value="six">Six</li>
    <li filter-value="seven">Seven</li>
    <li filter-value="eight">Eight</li>
    <li filter-value="nine">Nine</li>
    <li filter-value="ten" >Ten</li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x5amcaqr/